# Cannot get batch script to work

Tags: batch-file

The problem is with the script that if the process is running as admin the same as the batch script it wont work. It just doesn't find the process. Any help?
http://pastebin.com/qUrhxYrT

```
@echo off
title Unturned Server Restarter
echo Server Batch by :: Mage ::

:loop

echo (%time%) Loot Resetting...
start Unturned.exe -nographics -pei -normal -nosync -pvp -port:25444 -players:12 -sv -batchmode
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr Unturned.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
echo (%time%) Loot Reset.
echo (%time%) Server is online.
echo (%time%) Server Loot Resetting in 2 Hours.
timeout /t 10 >null
echo (%time%) Server Loot now resetting . . .
taskkill /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%

goto loop
```

Answer (score 0):

When you launch a batch file with elevated permissions then the working directory is set to the `system32` folder.

Presumably your script cannot find the `Unturned.exe` file, so using a `cd` command to set the working directory before the loop is one way to resolve an issue like that.

Comment: yeh but what would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

See your code below with full paths to all executables.

```
@echo off
title Unturned Server Restarter
echo Server Batch by :: Mage ::

:loop

echo (%time%) Loot Resetting...
start "Unturned" "%ProgramFiles%\team\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe" -nographics -pei -normal -nosync -pvp -port:25444 -players:12 -sv -batchmode
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe Unturned.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
echo (%time%) Loot Reset.
echo (%time%) Server is online.
echo (%time%) Server Loot Resetting in 2 Hours.
timeout /t 10 >null
echo (%time%) Server Loot now resetting . . .
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%

goto loop
```

As I don't know where `Unturned.exe` is installed on your computer, you may need to adapt the string `"%ProgramFiles%\team\steamapps\common\Unturned\Unturned.exe"`.

`%ProgramFiles%` is a reference to string value of environment variable **ProgramFiles** which contains usually `C:\Program Files`.

On 64-bit Windows there is also the environment variable **ProgramFiles(x86)** which needs to be used with `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` in batch code if `Unturned.exe` is installed somewhere below `C:\Program Files (x86)`.